# Prevent Android system from resuming task if the new Intent is the same with initial Intent that launches the app

Tags: java, android, android-intent, deep-linking

This question is related to deep link. For example, I have four activities in my app, namely `MainActivity`, `FirstActivity`, `SecondActivity`, and `DeepLinkActivity`. Here are the activities in the manifest file.

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity">
    <intent-filter>
       <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
       <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
<activity android:name=".FirstActivity" />
<activity android:name=".SecondActivity" />
<activity android:name=".DeepLinkActivity"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoDisplay">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <data android:scheme="launch" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

`DeepLinkActivity` will launch whether `FirstActivity`, `SecondActivity`, or `MainActivity` depending on the URI received:

```
public class DeepLinkActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        launchIntent(getIntent());
    }

    private void launchIntent(Intent intent) {
        Intent newIntent = null;

        switch (intent.getData().getHost()) {
            case "first":
                newIntent = new Intent(this, FirstActivity.class);
                break;
            case "second":
                newIntent = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
                break;
            default:
                newIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
                break;
        }

        startActivity(newIntent);
        finish();
    }
}
```

The problem is, Android system seems to record the initial Intent that launched the app, then uses it to resume whatever Activity is currently running in the foreground **-if-** the new Intent is the same with initial Intent.

Consider the following case:

1. User click `launch://first` deep link → `FirstActivity` is opened.
2. User minimize the app then click `launch://second` → `SecondActivity` is opened on top of `FirstActivity`.
3. User minimize the app again then click `launch://first`.

After step 3, what I expect is the OS open `FirstActivity`. But actually it resumes the task, so `SecondActivity` (from step 2) reappears. This happens because the deep link on step 1 and 3 is the same, hence the OS regards them as the same Intent.

How can I prevent the Android system from resuming task in this particular case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some trials this is what I did to get it working.

Setting the Flags for the `newIntent` before starting it:

```
newIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
```

However, setting the flags alone didn't do the job, the app is still resumed to the last activity. Then I add the launchMode to `DeepLinkActivity`:

```
<activity android:name=".DeepLinkActivity"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoDisplay"
    android:launchMode="singleTask">
```

Now the the app is restarted and open the expected activity! Note that the launchMode can be `singleInstance` as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can try defining something on the Activities OnPause function, to reset the intent every time the activity is paused.

Comment: I can't get a picture on how to do that. And even if I can define _something_ in the `onPause` method, I have to do that in all the Activities. 
Imagine if I have 100 different activities and before minimizing the app I navigate to some of them. That means I have to define that _something_ in the `onPause` method on all of the activities.